# Which is the correct way to add a huge amount of listeners to different elements in java?

Tags: java, javafx, listener

I have a controller class in a JavaFX program which is handling numerous Nodes. I created a method `addEventListeners` which looks like:

```
    cleanButton.setOnAction(e -> {
        ...
    });

    advSett.setOnAction(e -> {
        ...
    });

    imageLoaderItem.setOnAction(e -> {
        ...
    });

    outputButton.setOnAction(e -> {
        ...
    });
```

And so on for each element handled by the controller.
This method is occupying 300 lines of code making the controller class quite messy. I was wondering, is there a cleaner way of adding the listeners?

Comment: Do each of the listeners do the same thing? Then just define a variable holding the listener and pass it as a parameter. If it's not the same but there's a pattern, you might be able to make a method to return variants of the listener. And if they are all different, you will obviously have to write the code for each somewhere. The lambda syntax you're using is already pretty concise (for Java).

Comment: There are various things you can do, depending on the exact nature of your event handler logic. As well as the (excellent) suggestions from @Jorn, you can make the code (perhaps) tidier by defining methods for each action, and then either making the registration a one-liner (e.g. `cleanButton.setOnAction(e -> clean());`) or just referencing the methods directly from the FMXL. This can also help if the actions are closely related: `private void processNumericInput(int value) { ... }` and `button1.setOnAction(e -> processNumericInput(1));`, etc.

Comment: If the issue is really just that you have a very large number of controls, consider breaking the FXML into smaller, logically distinct, FXML files, each with their own controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is complementary and additional to [Vinz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74461788/1155209).  The information in this answer can be used in combination with the suggestions suggested in that answer or separately.

As noted in the [Introduction to FXML documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#fxml_annotation), you can directly associate events from FXML to Java or script code, using the `#` prefix on the event name in FXML.

Using the `#` injection method is a bit more succinct than invoking `setOnAction`. It is a matter of stylistic or personal preference as to which method to use.  Both approaches are valid and the results are identical.  Neither way is "correct" or "incorrect".

Paraphrasing from the documentation, given this definition:

```
<VBox fx:controller="com.foo.MyController"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <children>
        <Button text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction"/>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

You can write:

```
package com.foo;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class MyController {
    public void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
    }
}
```

Or, if you prefer using `@FXML` and not public methods, you can write:

```
package com.foo;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class MyController {
    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
    }
}
```

Further, the event parameter is optional, so you can just leave it out if not needed, and write:

```
package com.foo;

public class MyController {
    public void handleButtonAction() {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
    }
}
```

Any of the above methods is equivalent to writing (after also adding an `fx:id="button"` attribute in the FXML):

```
package com.foo;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class MyController implements Initializable {
    @FXML private Button button;

    @FXML
    protected void initialize()
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("You clicked me!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If multiple actions should have the same handler, you can reference the same handler name and implementation multiple times in the FXML file, like below:

```
<VBox fx:controller="com.foo.MyController"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <children>
        <Button text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction"/>
        <Button text="Click Me Too!" onAction="#handleButtonAction"/>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

Complementary question:

- [How to add event handling for Button object made in For Loop(JavaFX / Scenebuilder)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74509995/how-to-add-event-handling-for-button-object-made-in-for-loopjavafx-scenebuild)

Comment: Thanks @jewelsea, this is probably the best way to achieve what a was asking. 
But shouldn't the method declared with the FXML annotation be public?

Comment: *"shouldn't the method declared with the FXML annotation be public?"* -> No. If the `@FXML` annotated method were public, it would not need to be annotated `@FXML`.  See the [linked documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#fxml_annotation), "for developers who prefer more restricted visibility for controller fields or handler methods, the `javafx.fxml.FXML` annotation can be used. This annotation marks a protected or private class member as accessible to FXML".

Comment: Ok, then there was an error which I see you already adjusted. Thanks again

Comment: Yeah, in the answer I wrote "@FXML over public methods", meaning "instead of", but it kind can also mean "as well as", so was confusing, I made it clearer by changing the wording to "@FXML and not public methods".

Answer (score 1):

As correctly pointed out in the comments, splitting your Controller into several smaller ones is usually a good idea when you are facing such problems. Still, there are ways to avoid repetition of the same or similar instructions. If all your Buttons / Nodes do the same, you can simply do this:

```
private void addEventListener(final ButtonBase element) {
    element.setOnAction(e -> {
        //do the thing
    });
}
```

If most of your Nodes do the same and only two or three differ, then you can expand the same method like so:

```
private void addEventListener(final ButtonBase element) {
        if (element == cleanButton) {
            element.setOnAction(e -> {
                //do the thing
            });
        } else {
            element.setOnAction(e -> {
                //do the other thing
            });
        }
}
```

If you have identifyable groups of buttons that do the same, say group A doing x and group B doing y, then you can for example add them to a set each and handle them this way

```
private void addEventListener(final ButtonBase element) {
        if (groupA.contains(element)) {
            element.setOnAction(e -> {
                //do the thing for A
            });
        } else {
            element.setOnAction(e -> {
                //do the other thing
            });
        }
    }
```

Finally, you can also flip this on its head. If the common denominator is the event, rather than the Nodes, then you can also refactor your function to handle the event on the specific element it came from

```
private void handleButtonClicks(final javafx.event.ActionEvent mouseEvent) {
        switch (mouseEvent.getSource()) {
            case cleanButton:
                // and so on
            default:
     }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, what each listeners does is pretty diverse from the other. But I didn't think about splitting the controller in smaller ones. Answer accepted!